# Trying to find a young adult lit series with a girl with hidden magical powers

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find a young adult lit series about a girl who has hidden magical powers. The villain sends a boy (I  think named Eric) to bring her to him and he falls in love with her.
Along their way they make a friend who helps in the rescue of the girl later.

This book has a cartoon cover I think.

Thank you in advance, trying to find this for my classroom! I read it in the early 2000s

Answer (score 4):

The books you are seeking are Alma Alexander's Worldweavers novels.  The first book is called The Gift of the Unmage.  The other books in the series are Spellspam, Cybermage, and there will be a new one out called The Dawn of Magic.  They're back in print and published by Sky Warrior Books.  The book, The Gift of the Unmage, is about a girl who is supposed to be destined for greatness -- except it appears she has no magic.  But things are not as they appear, even when she is sent to the Wandless Academy, and only she and her group of misfit friends will be able to stop a terrible monster that is destroying everything in its path.

Comment: And is the hero named Eric?

Comment: This doesn't sound a lot like the OP's description ...

Comment: This isn't that series. I read it about 8 years ago and it is either an early 2000s series or 98/99 series